# BASH: Tailing a log file till the line matches an array

Tags: bash, minecraft

The thing I'm searching for is Player Death messages in the Minecraft logs.

So my script is watching the Minecraft server.log and I've created an array with all the possible death messages, but it just isn't working as it outputs ever line in the that appears in the logs.

```
#!/bin/bash

serverlog=/home/skay/NewWorld/server.log
outputfile=/home/skay/website/log/playerstats.log


##      File Creation!
if [ ! -f "$outputfile" ]; then
    touch $outputfile
    echo "file created"; else
    echo "file already existed"
fi

echo "Starting Loop"

while true; do

index="0"
newline=`tail -n 1 "$serverlog"`
joined=`tail -n 1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "joined the game"`
left=`tail -n 1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "left the game"`

##      Death Message Array
deathmsg=(  "was squashed by a falling anvil"
            "was pricked to death"
            "walked into a cactus whilst trying to escape"
            "was shot by arrow"
            "drowned"
            "blew up"
            "was blown up by"
            "hit the ground too hard"
            "fell from a high place"
            "fell off a ladder"
            "fell off some vines"
            "fell out of the water"
            "fell into a patch of fire"
            "fell into a patch of cacti"
            "was doomed to fall"
            "was shot off some vines by"
            "was shot off a ladder by"
            "was blown from a high place by"
            "went up in flames"
            "burned to death"
            "was burnt to a crisp whilst fighting"
            "walked into a fire whilst fighting"
            "was slain by"
            "was shot by"
            "was fireballed by"
            "was killed by"
            "got finished off by"
            "was slain by"
            "tried to swim in lava"
            "died"
            "got finished off by"
            "was slain by"
            "was shot by"
            "was killed by"
            "was killed by magic"
            "starved to death"
            "suffocated in a wall"
            "was killed while trying to hurt"
            "fell out of the world"
            "fell from a high place and fell out of the world"
            "was knocked into the void by"
            "withered away")


##      Player Joined
    if [ "$newline" != "$oldline" ]; then
        if [ "$newline" == "$joined" ]; then
            echo "$joined"
            oldline="$newline"
        fi

##      Player Disconnected
        if [ "$newline" == "$left" ]; then
            echo "$left"
            oldline="$newline"
        fi

##      Player Death Message
        while [ "$index" -le "42" ]; do 
            death=`tail -n 1 $serverlog | grep "[INFO]" | grep "${deathmsg[$index]}"`
            if [ "$newline" == "$death" ]; then
                echo "$death"
                oldline="$death"
            fi
            index=$[$index+1]
        done
    fi
done
```

Example of the server.log:

```
2013-07-21 00:38:36 [SEVERE] Reached end of stream for /79.97.91.46
2013-07-21 00:38:38 [INFO] Fenlig[/79.97.91.46:59709] logged in with entity id 880461 at (541.34081297678, 48.0, 463.3734054913931)
2013-07-21 00:38:38 [INFO] Fenlig joined the game
Player Fenlig login detected
2013-07-21 00:39:49 [INFO] Fenlig was doomed to fall
2013-07-21 00:39:57 [INFO] Fenlig lost connection: disconnect.quitting
2013-07-21 00:39:57 [INFO] Fenlig left the game
```

Comment: What's your question? What does the log file look like?

Comment: @franklin

Here is a example of the log
`2013-07-21 00:38:36 [SEVERE] Reached end of stream for /79.97.91.46
2013-07-21 00:38:38 [INFO] Fenlig[/79.97.91.46:59709] logged in with entity id 880461 at (541.34081297678, 48.0, 463.3734054913931)
2013-07-21 00:38:38 [INFO] Fenlig joined the game
2013-07-21 00:39:49 [INFO] Fenlig was doomed to fall
2013-07-21 00:39:57 [INFO] Fenlig lost connection: disconnect.quitting
2013-07-21 00:39:57 [INFO] Fenlig left the game`

Comment: Have you tried to figure out where the problem is? For example: which `echo` statement is printing out lines that you didn't intend to be printed? If it's the `echo "$death"` statement, then -- which `$index` is the problem?

Comment: The echo "$death" is just echoing any line in the log rather than the ones that share the arrays strings. Sorry for poor explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andy answer is a better way to go; you could do something like that just with bash, too.

But to answer to directly to the question, I think your problem is that you are getting index up to 42, and

```
$ echo ${deathmsg[42]}

$
```

As the array index starts with 0, it ends with 41. 42 is blank, and then the last grep on the death= line matches.

Answer (score 0):

You ever thought about using awk? Write this into parse_log.awk

```
{
  /* only process [INFO] messages */
  if ($3 == "[INFO]") {
    rest_of_string = substr($0, index($0, $4));

    /* logged in, and anything else you want to skip ... */
    if ($5 == "logged") {
      next;
    }

    /* joined ... */
    if ($5 == "joined") {
      print rest_of_string;
      next;
    }

    /* left ... */
    if ($5 == "left") {
      print rest_of_string;
      next;
    }

    /* otherwise death */
    print rest_of_string;
  }
}
```

Then on the command line you can simply run this

$ tail -n 1 -f /home/skay/website/log/playerstats.log | awk -f parse_log.awk >> /home/skay/website/log/playerstats.log

In essence, tail keeps following the log (-f), then pipes that to your awk program which, if it produces output, appends it to your file